# How to list all sub-directories containing a file

Tags: linux, file, shell, directory

I have to accomplish the following task:

For a given list of filenames and for a given directory print for each filename all the sub-directories in which it appears. The sub-directories will be printed in a decending order based on the creation date of the file.

I have no idea how to do it

Comment: post what you have tried so far, and the areas where you're having difficulty with.

Comment: Agreed, show us what you have and seek clarification on the hard parts. You won't get far asking people to do your homework for you (how would you learn?)

Comment: I think the question is ambigious too. Did you get given an example set of files/directories to work against?

Comment: The problem is ill posed.  Unless you are using a non-standard file system, the creation date of the file is not available.

Answer (score 1):

Because coming up with the personal favourite solution is big fun, I'll join in:

#### Solution (Spoiler)

### @user unknown:

I know you're trolling, but in the interest of casual readers: 
I admit that the inline expansions there are not safe indeed. I was really showing how I had intended to use the commands (ls, find, uniq) etc. in combination. It can be made safe:

```
find -type f -printf '%f\0' | sort -uz |
    xargs -0i -n1 find -name {} -printf "%f:%p\n"
```

The formatting is slightly less convenient now (then again, *how* would you format it with special characters in the pathnames?). The question says little on that subject, so...

---

*One final note:*

`the first read is already broken with (...) blanks in filenames`

- **untrue** `while read` is only broken with newlines, try it: `read line <<< "a b c" && echo "'$line'"`

#### Original Didactic Pointers

Use

```
dirname
     a/b/c/file -> a/b/c
basename
     a/b/c/file -> file
ls -t / ls -tr
     sort files by timestamp; note that 'creation date' is likely a fob because hardly any filesystem stores these reliably (it is usually the last change date for the inode)

find -type f
find -type d
     find files or directories
sort | uniq
sort -u
     sort lines and remove adjacent (subsequent) duplicates
```

Let me know if that helped. I could give you a tiny step-up besides the pointers to the UNIX commands

Comment: You don't need dirname, basename, ls -t, ls -tr, uniq or sort -u. Uniqueness was no requierement.

Comment: Show me your solution, then we'll talk :)

Comment: I did :) As well as implement my own conceptual solution, so you can confirm for yourself that _[Tim Toady](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)_

Comment: I'm sorry, but your program generates such output for me: `: . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ` if I feed it with my filelist. The orignial program, which generates its own filelist from what it finds, diverging from the task to solve, yields many error messages `ls: cannot access noch.mp: No such file or directory
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.` It only works with sanitized dir- and filenames. Reasons are: The first `read fname` is already broken with (...)

Comment: (...) blanks in filenames. The next part: `$(ls -t $(find -name "$fname")` again doesn't prevent wordsplitting at blanks, as well as xargs. Put some filenames with blanks, and directorynames with such in your test lab, and try again.

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in $(< filelist) 
do 
    find -name "$file" -printf "%C@ %h\n" | sort -rn | sed 's/^[0-9.]* //'
done
```

- $(< filelist) is a redirection, which avoids a new process (opposed to cat)
- printf %C@ prints the time in seconds since 1.1.1970
- %h prints the leading directories without filename
- sort -n sorts numerical, -r reverse order
- sed removes the time after sorting

#### Problems:

- From the question, there is no indication to print the filename itself, which is unusual for a real world scenario. It would be easily solved.
- Pathnames with linebreaks are poorly handled, as well as other fancy characters like vertical tab, form feed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `for` (to loop over your files) and `find` to search for your files.

```
cat > filenames <<EOF
file-a
file-b
file-c
EOF

export DIR=dir-d

for filename in `cat filenames`; do find $DIR -name $filename ; done
```

Check the 'find' man page for what more you can do to; you can easily run other commands (with  `-exec`).

Comment: You don't need to export `DIR`, just assign: `DIR=dir-d`.

Comment: Something should be left to the student. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The creation date of the file is not normally available.  On standard file systems, you can access the last modification time, the last access time, and the last time the metadata changed.  Other than that issue, here's a nice script to do the other portion:

```
#!/bin/sh

F=$(mktemp)
trap "rm -f $F" 0
find ${1?Usage: $(basename $0) path [file...]} > $F
shift
while test $# -gt 0; do
  grep $1 $F
  shift
done
```

One nice feature of this script is that it only runs find once.  To do the sorting, one good technique would be to print the statistic on which you want to sort into the tempfile and then simply pipe the output of the while loop to sort.  As noted in a comment, the grep is not particularly reliable as it may match paths that are not exact matches.

Comment: @karaszi Yes, the ordering is missing.  Note the text above the script.

Comment: also, grepping for the file name in find results is not very reliable; it might match anywhere in the wholepath; +1 for using  `mktemp` properly

Answer (score 0):

It works only under Linux, but that was in the OP:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in fileNameA fileNameB; do
  echo "File ${file} is in the following directories:"
  find sourceDir -type f -name ${file} -printf "%T@\t%h\n"|sort -rn|cut -f2
done
```

*Hint:* If you omit the `cut -f2` part you can see the creation (last modification) time as well for the files.

Comment: cut -d2 or -f2? If I omit it, I see, that for very old files, sort fails without -n switch.